# wordpress changing admin login url from http to https, then it doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, http, https

I used Wordpress, **changing admin login URL from http to https**, and I could not login into the back-end. I tried to find the answer on the internet, but their answer always had to use phpmyadmin to solve. **I didn't use phpmyadmin to build my website**, only used some basic functions from Wordpress. So does anyone can help me plz? thx

Answer (score 0):

Does your site have an SSL certificate?  You can contact your hosting company to ask them to install an SSL and then you should be able to access the backend using https.

Otherwise you'll probably need to disable that plugin. If it's forcing https but you don't have ability to use https then you won't be able to access.

Probably need to access site files using FTP and delete that plugin folder. Contact your hosting company for help if you're not familiar with that process.

Comment: ok thank u~ I will try your suggestions